# APNS Error: The authentication or decryption has failed

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono, apple-push-notifications

I tried PushSharp and now a "regular" APNS request, but it's not working.

Here's my implementation:

```
int port = 2195;
            String hostname = "gateway.push.apple.com";
            //String certificatePath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("cio_aps_development.p12");
            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("cio_aps_development.p12"), "");
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
                writer.Write((byte)0);
                writer.Write((byte)0);
                writer.Write((byte)32);

                writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(user.SmartphoneInfo.DeviceToken.ToUpper()));
                String payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + "Hi,, This Is a Sample Push Notification For IPhone.." + "\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}";
                writer.Write((byte)0);
                writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
                byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
                writer.Write(b1);
                writer.Flush();
                byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
                sslStream.Write(array);
                sslStream.Flush();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                client.Close();
            }
```

But I always get the error:

```
System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:430 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:256 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x002c6] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:502 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.EndNegotiateHandshake (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00035] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:396 
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0000c] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:101 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.EndRead (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00051] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslStreamBase.cs:883 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00011] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:475 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.LegacySslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/LegacySslStream.cs:445 
  at Mono.Net.Security.Private.MonoSslStreamImpl.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/Mono.Net.Security/MonoSslStreamImpl.cs:77 
  at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0/bockbuild-xamarin/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Security/SslStream.cs:147 
  at Claims.Api.Infrastructure.Notifications.Notify.AppleTest (Claims.User user, System.String text) [0x00059] in /Users/eestein/Documents/dev/claims-api/claims-api/Src/Claims.Api/Infrastructure/Notifications/Notify.cs:85
```

If I run:

`certmgr -ssl ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`

I get the same error.

What could be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: `ssl://`? did you mean `https://`?

Comment: @knocte it's actually correct, it's `ssl://` Thanks.